# visual code error: how do i fix this problem

Tags: c

I'm super new to coding I have downloaded Visual Studio and as I'm writing my first program I get this error

> symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "_main", referenced from:
> implicit entry/start for main executable
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't understand what to do. I have read in come post to see if I have a compiler and I believe I do
Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.27.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

this was my code

```
 #include <stdio.h>`int main() {printf("helloh world");return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a

```
`
```

in your code that's not needed and you lack white spaces between your `include` directive and your function declaration. Try it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("helloh world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it still showing me this error Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)